# Extending an sObject in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, inheritance

Some time ago I was interested in creating a class that would extend one of the custom objects, so I can make some instance methods or other stuff that would be helpful in apex logic. Pretty quickly I realized that it cannot be done ootb and it's explained here [How to add an instance method to a custom SObject?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/how-to-add-an-instance-method-to-a-custom-sobject) .
I came up with a workaround, but my gut tells me this is a bad idea.
Say I have a custom object called 'MyProduct__c'. The object has two fields: 'field1__c', 'field2__c'. What I could do is make a class that represents a base of that custom object:

```
public with sharing abstract class BaseMyProduct {

public Id Id;
public String Name;
public String field1_mco;
public String field2_mco;

public BaseMyProduct() {

}
public BaseMyProduct(MyProduct__c sObj) {
    Id = sObj.Id;
    Name = sObj.Name;
    field1_mco = sObj.field1__c;
    field2_mco = sObj.field2__c;
}

public MyProduct__c toProduct() {
    return (MyProduct__c )JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(this).replaceAll('_mco', '__c'), MyProduct__c.class);
}

public static MyProduct__c toSObject(BaseMyProduct customTc) {
    return (MyProduct__c )JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(customTc).replaceAll('_mco', '__c'), MyProduct__c.class);
}
public static List<MyProduct__c> toSObjects(List<BaseMyProduct> customTcs) {
    return (List<MyProduct__c>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(customTcs).replaceAll('_mco', '__c'), List<MyProduct__c>.class);
}
```

The class has all relevant fields, and the custom field suffix '__c' is replaced by something else, in my case it's '_mco'.

With this base class I can implement others that extend this one, implement some method helpers there:

```
public with sharing class MyCustomProduct extends BaseMyProduct {

public MyCustomProduct() { }
public void doStuff() { ... }

}
```

do whatever logic I have to do and cast everything with 'toSobjects' or 'toProduct' methods to be able to perform a dml. The example is kind of lame and may not necessarily illustrate why I'm trying to do that, I can figure out a better one if that's necessary.
Would that work fine? Is there a better solution? For some reason I have a bad feeling about the JSON serializing and deserializing, but wasn't able to test it on a larger DML operation to see if it breaks on larger structures.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that JSON should be avoided entirely. It is a huge performance penalty to use serialization in Apex, as a general rule. I would say a much better structure is to just store the record itself as an attribute.

```
public with sharing class MyWrapper
{
    final SObject record;
    public MyWrapper(SObject record) { this.record = record; }
    public void doStuff() { /*implementation*/ }
}
```

Structurally, if you find this wrapper concept useful, the above is the most appropriate (simplest) design. However, I would caution that you have a paradigm mismatch if you are trying to apply this concept to trigger logic,  as it focus on single record processing, whereas your trigger logic should focus on *collections* of data (`List<SObject>`). Use this pattern only for controller bound logic.

A couple notes:

- Try to use whole words for your variable names
- As far as naming goes, a single instance of an `SObject` is a *record*

Comment: Agreed, round-trip de/serialization is excessive here (using a shotgun to shoot a fly). Using composition here instead of inheritance accomplishes the same goal (perhaps sacrificing a little extra typing in client classes for a much lighter footprint on CPU limit/processing time).

Comment: Yeah, I understand the wrapper thing and I also understand the necessity of processing everything in collections, I'm just trying to figure out a neater, more readable solutions. Thanks